# How to do I refer to a result of a function in a template? django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have these models:

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)


    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def avg_rating(User):
        return UserProfile.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']


# this is the model for user ratings - one to many relationship with User
class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    for_username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.rating)
```

I want to refer to the result of the property (avg_rating) in my template so I can show the rating of each user. I tried this it it shows blank result:

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user.profile.avg_rating }}
```

Also, this is the view being invoked:

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.select_related().order_by('-userrating')[:5]

    city_list = City.objects.order_by('-name')[:5]

    context_dict = {"users": user_list, "cities" : city_list}

    return render(request, "index.html", context_dict)
```

I'm currently learning my way through Django, sorry if this is very obvious.

Comment: As Selcuk says in his answer, the problem is with the `avg_rating` property. Note that the template can hide errors like this. If you are adding a new method or property, it's a good idea to try printing the result in the shell or view, then you'll see error messages rather than silent failures.

Answer (score 3):

The `User` argument of your `avg_rating` is not used at all. Try rewriting it as:

```
def avg_rating(self):
    return self.user.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

You can also remove the `@property` decorator as you can also use methods in Django templates using the same syntax (ie. without `()`), such as:

```
{{ user.profile.avg_rating }}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm receiving this error now:    'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'userrating_set'. I have Django's built-in User model with one to one relationship with UserProfile and one to many with UserRating

Answer (score 2):

UserRating is related to User, not UserProfile. You'd need to make the query against that model.

But note that the way you're doing it is extremely expensive, given that it requires an extra query+aggregation for every single user. Instead you should do the query in the view, via the `annotation` method that works on all elements in a queryset.

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.select_related().annotate(
        rating=Avg('userrating__rating')
    ).order_by('-rating')[:5]
```

Now you can refer to each user's rating via `{{ user.rating }}` in the template.

Comment: I'm receiving this error after testing the page. global name 'userrating__rating' is not defined. I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize userrating.

Comment: Sorry, should have been in quotes. Try now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is showing the rating now but they're not ordered by average (it appears: 50, 100, 0, 35) and if I give a user two ratings it appears twice instead of calculating the average and putting it in the right spot.

Comment: To sort by the average rating, sort by the annotated field `'-rating'` instead of `'-userrating'`. That should also prevent the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Things like def avg_rating like to be set as Manager method. It may be better idea to create Manager class for UserProfile (UserProfileManager for example) to deal all queries of UserProfile model. The avg_rating definition would prefer to live in this UserProfileManager.

2)
The avg_rating definition is related to UserProfile so it should be call as UserProfile method not User method.

3)
Setting avg_rating in UserProfile class may be confusing while UserRating class is created for rating stuff.